# Can checkbox label be positioned above instead left/right?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In the [official docs](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/checkbox) it is stated the Checkbox component has a prop labelPosition that accepts values right and left.
I wanted to display the label above the actual checkbox element.

Can that be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Type of labelPosition is enum(left, right) so you can only pass left or right into component. 
But you can try use css, jquery.